# Can't figure out why my while loop is getting stuck

Tags: c#, list, random, while-loop

Currently working on writing code for a Windows Forms version of the card game war.  I needed a way to shuffle the list to randomize the deck.  I have already defined the lists for deck and shuffledDeck as a list of strings.

When I run createDeck(), I had it output to a textbox in my windows form to ensure that it is infact creating the list properly.  I also had it test to ensure that deck.Count() was equal to 52

```
private void shuffle()
        {
            createDeck();
            shuffledDeck = deck;
            Random r = new Random();
            int randomIndex = 0;
            while (deck.Count > 0)
            {
                randomIndex = r.Next(0, deck.Count);
                shuffledDeck.Add(deck[randomIndex]);
                deck.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
            }
```

This is my testing that the deck is in fact shuffled

```
            for (int a = 0; a <= 51; a++)
            {
                textBox1.Text += " " + shuffledDeck[a];
            }
```

I would expect that I would see a shuffled deck each time however whenever I run it, Visual Studio freezes and I am have to force quit the program to exit.

Comment: [Use your debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). `shuffledDeck = deck`, so they are the same deck, not a copy. Every time you add a card to `shuffledDeck` and remove one from `deck` you are adding and removing a card from the same deck, so obviously you will never run out of cards.

Comment: deck.Count is always > 0

Comment: shuffledDeck = deck => it is the same object

Comment: **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** UI controls, like MessageBox, are feeble debugging aides.

Answer (score 2):

The line `shuffledDeck = deck;` makes `shuffledDeck` and `deck` a reference to the same object. So inside your while loop, you are removing and adding "cards" to the same deck and the condition deck.Count > 0 will always be true.

Try using this object cloner: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

And replace `shuffledDeck = deck;` with `shuffledDeck = deck.Clone();`